# Ubuntu does not load

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, mount, fstab

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 back in 2017 on 32 bits old laptop. I had to access my cd rom to look up some pictures and cd rom drive was not working. I went /etc/fstab file and monkey around without understanding. Ubuntu was not loading and I was receiving  errors. I deleted the fstab file. Ubuntu will not load.The fstab file was saved as /etc/fstab~ under /etc file. I went to recovery modeand took fsck option the prompt came back with finished. I took resume option from recovery menu option. Ubuntu still was not not working. so rebooted in recovery mode and went to root prompt. I issue # mount -o  remount,rw / and rebooted again. It is still not working.My fstab file looks as foollow:

```
# /etc/fstab:Static file system Information
#
#Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifie for a
#device;this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
#that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5) .
#
#<file system>  <mount point>  <type> <option>  <dump>  <pass>
proc   /proc          proc   nodev,noexec,nosuid  0     0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installaon
UUID=bc092328-5f07-4614-bc9b-cfbb61fc8a7d /                 ext4   errors=remount-rw 0
#swap was on /dev/sda5 during installaon
UUID=6cb7cdbc-7666-48e0-8d34-efcd8c79f7a3 none    swap    rw     0     0
#dev/cdrom   /mnt/cdrom    iso9660 auto,user   0  0
#dev/hdc  /media/cdrom0 udf ,iso9660   user 0  0
#dev/cdrom    /mnt/cdrom    auto  noauto,user    0  0
#dev/sr0  /media/cdrom  udf ,iso9660  user ,noauto  0
```

Permisssion for fstab are rwxrwxrwx. I  ubuntu 16.04 cd but It will not boot. I am not sure if CD is bad or I did not mount correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the laptop has USB ports, and if there is no precious information on the laptop or else that's all backed up, I would suggest doing a fresh install from a usb thumbdrive. Ubuntu has tutorials for creating the thumbdrive [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials?q=bootable).

Comment: Thank you Julian. I will create thumbdrive and reinstall it. Once again thank you.

Comment: No problem! If this answer fixed your issue, you can click the check mark near the up & down arrows to the left of the text to indicate that you accept it and that your issue has been resolved.